# Adding data to JSON after XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Well, having a head scratching moment.

I'm trying to **add** additional **data** to my **object** after I request it from an external site (just for testing, I plan on adding random values)

I'll just cut to the chase:

**For example purposes, my `test.json` file looks like this:**

```
[["month",[-150,100,0.7]]]
```

**And after acquiring the `JSON` file, I need it to look like this:**

```
[["month",[-150,100,0.7,24,24,0.5]]]
```

#### Request:

```
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', '/test.json', true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
          var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

          // Trying to add this as an additional array
          data[0].push([24,24,0.5]);

          window.data = data;
          for (i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
            globe.addData(data[i][1], {format: 'magnitude', name: data[i][0], animated: true});
          }
          globe.createPoints();
          settime(globe,0)();
          globe.animate();
          document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'none'; // remove loading
        }
      }
    };
    xhr.send(null);
```

Here's a screenshot of the hierarchy that I see with `dev tools`:

[image: Adding it as a new array, making an even deeper multi-dimensional array instead of just adding to the existing one.]

It's adding the data deeper into the model... I'm just a bit lost how to structure this.

(Making a project with the WebGL - Globe Google Project, FYI)

Any easier way if I have a data-set than just doing...?

```
data[0][1].push(24);
data[0][1].push(24);
data[0][1].push(0.5);
```

Comment: `.push()` can take multiple parameters, so you could do `data[0][1].push(24, 24, 0.5);`.

Comment: So I'm just a goofball and added it AS an array like a tard? lol

Comment: Don't beat yourself up too bad...we've all made these mistakes. But if the new values you want to append are stored as an array in a variable, then @ArtyomNeustroev's answer below looks like a good solution.

Comment: Thanks :-) [View Live Here with added Data](http://sinsysonline.com/globe/)

Comment: Essentially this will be a synchronous function. I'm going to cache the most recent 10 requests... now I need to figure out how to remove the values after the 11th request lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
 var yourArray = [24,24,0.5];
 data[0][1] = data[0][1].concat(yourArray);
```

Or use `apply` with `push`:

```
data[0][1].push.apply(data[0][1], yourArray);
```